# Problems when I try to run npm

Tags: nodejs, npm

When I try to run `sudo npm start` in my project folder to run it in localhost, it return me following:

```
kallel@augustinho:~/PDIAP-master$ sudo npm start
pdiap@0.2.0 start /home/kallel/PDIAP-master 
nodemon bin/www --exec babel-node --presets es2015
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node bin/www --presets es2015`
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:328
        throw e;
        ^
Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/home/kallel/PDIAP-master"
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
   at Array.map (native)
   at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:103:45)
at loader (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:14)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7) 
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's with the same problem, just install locally with the npm the package it says is missing with the command `sudo npm install [package-asked]`.

On my case, I had to run `sudo npm install es2015` and the consequent asked packages until it with was solved.

Have a good night. :)